# Javascript simple problem, show div and call function on certain day

Tags: javascript

Guys I've got a problem. I'm very ill-experienced with javascript. I basically want to show a div on fridays and also call the lightning() function on Fridays. Yes it's a horrible script and you can guess where it's going but I can't figure out how to call both using my current script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    <!--
    //Lighting script
    var flash=0
    function lightning()
    {flash=flash+1;
    if(flash==1){document.bgColor='green'; setTimeout("lightning()",100);}
    if(flash==2){document.bgColor='black'; setTimeout("lightning()",90);}
    if(flash==3){document.bgColor='red'; setTimeout("lightning()",85);}
    if(flash==4){document.bgColor='blue'; setTimeout("lightning()",80);}
    if(flash==5){document.bgColor='purple'; setTimeout("lightning()",75);}
    if(flash==6){document.bgColor='green'; setTimeout("lightning()",70);}
    if(flash==7){document.bgColor='black'; setTimeout("lightning()",65);}
    if(flash==8){document.bgColor='red'; setTimeout("lightning()",60);}
    if(flash==9){document.bgColor='blue'; setTimeout("lightning()",50);}
    if(flash==10){document.bgColor='purple'; setTimeout("lightning()",40);}
    if(flash==11){document.bgColor='black'; setTimeout("lightning()",30);}
    if(flash==12){document.bgColor='red'; setTimeout("lightning()",25);}
    if(flash==13){document.bgColor='red'; setTimeout("lightning()",20);}
    if(flash==14){document.bgColor='blue'; setTimeout("lightning()",10);}
    if(flash==15){document.bgColor='purple'; setTimeout("lightning()",5);}
    if(flash==16){document.bgColor='white'; setTimeout("lightning()",1);}
    if(flash==17){document.bgColor='black'; setTimeout("lightning()",1);}
    if(flash==18){document.bgColor='blue'; setTimeout("lightning()",1);}
    if(flash==19){document.bgColor='purple'; setTimeout("lightning()",1);}
    if(flash==20){flash=0; setTimeout("lightning()",100);}
    }

    // -->

    onload=function(){
        var rightNow = new Date();
        var day = rightNow.getDay();
        var hour = rightNow.getHours();
        var minute = rightNow.getMinutes();
        var formDisplay = 'none'; // unless we see otherwise
        var forwardDisplay = 'block'; // unless we see otherwise

        if(day==1 || day==2  ||  day==3  ||  day==4 ) {  // friday friday, got to get down on Friday            if((hour>=1)  &&  (hour<=24)) // if chat is avalable between these times
                formDisplay = 'block', forwardDisplay = 'none'; 

            }

            }


    document.getElementById('friday').style.display = formDisplay; 
    document.getElementById('friday').style.display = forwardDisplay; 

    }

    // alert('Test Alert')
    </script>

    <div id='friday' >
    <object width="560" height="349"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/CD2LRROpph0?fs=1&autoplay=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;hd=1"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/CD2LRROpph0?fs=1&autoplay=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;hd=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="560" height="349"></embed></object>
    </div>
```

Could anybody point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Whats holding you up?  Is it actually figuring out whether or not its friday, putting the page together in general?

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for responding. I'm struggling with a way to show both the div on Friday's and call the lightning function. The script is correctly figuring out if it's Friday. I'm unfamiliar with the syntax and how to call both using the current script, nothing I try works.

Comment: Good lord, that `lighting()` function is nightmarish.

Comment: Why do you have an html comment in your javascript? I don't think you need browser support for Netscape 1.

Comment: It looks beautiful in action. You've helped me create a monster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clean this up so it's easier to see what's going on. Replace your onload function with this.

```
onload=function(){
  var rightNow = new Date();
  var day = rightNow.getDay();
  var isFriday = (day == 5);
  if(isFriday){
    document.getElementById('friday').style.display = 'block';
    lightning();
  } else {
    document.getElementById('friday').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: Mike, thank you ever so much. That's perfect; I Just a little confused with the syntax. You're a good man.

Answer (score 2):

This?

```
if(day===5 ) { //if Friday
    formDisplay = 'block';
    forwardDisplay = 'none'; 
    lightning();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, this snippet seems to ignore 'what day it is' and sets off that annoying little flashing function regardless of day. I need it to go off on day==5 only.

Comment: That's odd, there's a check for day==5 right there. Either way, you seem to have got a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post how this part could be cleaned up:

```
//Lighting script
var flash = 0;
var timeout = 0;
var color = '';

function lightning() {
    flash = flash + 1;

    if (flash === 1) { color = 'green'; timeout = 100; }
    else if (flash === 2) { color = 'black'; timeout = 90; }
    else if (flash === 3) { color = 'red'; timeout = 85; }
    else if (flash === 4) { color = 'blue'; timeout = 80; }
    else if (flash === 5) { color = 'purple'; timeout = 75; }
    else if (flash === 6) { color = 'green'; timeout = 70; }
    else if (flash === 7) { color = 'black'; timeout = 65; }
    else if (flash === 8) { color = 'red'; timeout = 60; }
    else if (flash === 9) { color = 'blue'; timeout = 50; }
    else if (flash === 10) { color = 'purple'; timeout = 40; }
    else if (flash === 11) { color = 'black'; timeout = 30; }
    else if (flash === 12) { color = 'red'; timeout = 25; }
    else if (flash === 13) { color = 'red'; timeout = 20; }
    else if (flash === 14) { color = 'blue'; timeout = 10; }
    else if (flash === 15) { color = 'purple'; timeout = 5; }
    else if (flash === 16) { color = 'white'; timeout = 1; }
    else if (flash === 17) { color = 'black'; timeout = 1; }
    else if (flash === 18) { color = 'blue'; timeout = 1; }
    else if (flash === 19) { color = 'purple'; timeout = 1; }
    else if (flash === 20) { flash = 0; timeout = 100; }

            document.bgColor = color;

    setTimeout(function() {
        lightning();
    }, timeout);
}
```

Or with switch/case syntax:

```
//Lighting script
var flash = 0;
var timeout = 0;
var color = '';

function lightning() {
    flash = flash + 1;

    switch (flash) {
        case 1: color = 'green'; timeout = 100; break;
        case 2: color = 'black'; timeout = 90; break;
        case 3: color = 'red'; timeout = 85; break;
        case 4: color = 'blue'; timeout = 80; break;
        case 5: color = 'purple'; timeout = 75; break;
        case 6: color = 'green'; timeout = 70; break;
        case 7: color = 'black'; timeout = 65; break;
        case 8: color = 'red'; timeout = 60; break;
        case 9: color = 'blue'; timeout = 50; break;
        case 10: color = 'purple'; timeout = 40; break;
        case 11: color = 'black'; timeout = 30; break;
        case 12: color = 'red'; timeout = 25; break;
        case 13: color = 'red'; timeout = 20; break;
        case 14: color = 'blue'; timeout = 10; break;
        case 15: color = 'purple'; timeout = 5; break;
        case 16: color = 'white'; timeout = 1; break;
        case 17: color = 'black'; timeout = 1; break;
        case 18: color = 'blue'; timeout = 1; break;
        case 19: color = 'purple'; timeout = 1; break;
        case 20: flash = 0; timeout = 100; break;
    }   

    document.bgColor = color;

    setTimeout(function () {
        lightning();
    }, timeout);
}
```

Comment: Might be even better to use a switch statement here.

Comment: I was going to use a switch at first, but then the scrolling in this window would have been loooong. Screw it, i'll put it in anyway.